# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'customtkinter' using Raspberry Pi and openbox

Tags: linux, tkinter, raspberry-pi, openbox, raspberry-pi-os

I am using a Raspberry Pi and the lite version of the OS. My goal is to run a python script using customtkinter.
As I am using the lite-version of the OS, I run the script with xorg and openbox (tutorial: https://forums.raspberrypi.com//viewtopic.php?t=152264)

Executing the file that runs my script in openbox, I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'customtkinter'
```

Customtkinter is installed.

The python script itself is executable, if I try running the .py file itself, I get the following error:

```
tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

That means, the file itself doesn't have the problem of importing customtkinter as the above error is caused in line 35 and I'm importing customtkinter in line 2.

So somehow running the file in openbox causes the problem of not finding the customtkinter module. How can I fix this?
PS: There is no problem importing other libraries such as Tkinter

Comment: It is working for me. Please check if you're using any virtual environment (if yes, then please activate them and work with it). If still you're getting error, please share the steps of your installation and then add screenshots if possible.

Comment: I'm not using any virtual environment (I guess?!). You did the exact same thing with customtkinter and it works just fine?

Comment: Can you try setting your DISPLAY environment and see if that works? Run this on the command line.

export DISPLAY=:0.0

Comment: If I run "export DISPLAY=:0.0" and try to execute my python programm directly in the command line, I get the error "tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ':0.0'". No differences running the code in openbox.

Answer (score 0):

I was banging my head against this same issue with a python GUI in openbox I am building.

While analyzing the python path within the application I did notice one of the local package folders was not present when run through openbox. Running the below:

```
import sys

print(sys.path)
```

Almost all paths in the array were the same except a `xxxxxx/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages` directory. This was present when running the python app through command line but not present when running `sudo startx openbox-session.` If you then add the following to the openbox environment file:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:xxxxxxxx/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

either in `$HOME/.config/openbox/environment` or `/etc/xdg/openbox/environment` then that resolves the import issue.

---

<s>The PythonPath variable might not be set to include that .local subpath because of the use of `sudo` but I haven't been able to verify this yet since I get a ~`/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server` for non-sudo users.</s>

**EDIT:** I was able to run `startx open-session` after reinstalling the packages and modifying some startx configs and can confirm my suspicision. The `$HOME/.local` path isn't added in when running with sudo. If you were using sudo previously, not using sudo would be my recommended fix.

Your situation might be different though, especially how your running openbox or setting its environment.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to activate your desktop environment, using the simple `startx` command. If you don't have a desktop environment installed on your Pi, you can use apt, apt-get or aptitude to install any desktop environment of your choice.